# How to save excel file with incrementing number?

Tags: excel, vba, increment

I am looking for VBA to add to my macro that will increment the file name if the file name already exists.

Current Code:

```
Dim filepath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim filepatharch As String
Dim filedate As String
Dim filelist As String

'Grab FROM list number
Sheets("TD File").Select
Range("G4").Select
filelist = ActiveCell.Value


'Grab today's date
filedate = Format(Now, "MMDD01.") --------------Currently where the '01' comes from (see below)

'Set where to save and the file naming convention
filepath = "\\home\serverfolder\FileDrop\"
tdfilename = "TD" & filedate & filelist
'& ".txt"


'Set where to save and the file naming convention
filepatharch = "\\home\myfolder\archive"
tdfilename = "TD" & filedate & filelist
'& ".txt"


'Save THXXXXXX.XXX & TDXXXXXX.XXX as flat files
   'Workbooks("MYWORK01").Activate
    Sheets("TDflatfile").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:= _
        "\\home\serverfolder\FileDrop\" & tdfilename, FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
```

An example of the saved file name would be "TD101401.600". TD + MMDD + 01 + .XXX. I would like the "+ 01 " to be the number that increments, that way I could have a file that is "TD101402.600" and so forth. Currently if the file exists for the same .XXX number and date combo, it gets overwritten. The .XXX cannot be the increment.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can use Dir() to see if the filename already exists, and increment a counter until you find an un-used name.  Try that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone suggested this and it worked for me:

```
Dim filecount As Integer

Do While Len(Dir(filepatharch & thfilename)) <> 0
        filecount = filecount + 1
        filedate = Format(Now, "MMDD0" & filecount & ".")
        tdfilename = "TD" & filedate & filelist
        thfilename = "TH" & filedate & filelist
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a conditional loop with `Dir()`

```
Do While ((Dir(filepath & tdfilename)) <> Empty)
inc = inc+1
filedate = Format(Now, "MMDD") & "." & Format(inc, "00")
tdfilename = "TD" & filedate & filelist
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful (just needed to remove the "Then" at the end of the first line).